# How to web scrape tags for Stack Overflow questions using beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'post-tag'}):
        # href = link.get('href')
        for i in link:
            title = link.string
        print(title)`

Output: python
floating-point
rounding
python
None
google-colaboratory
python
flask
python
beautifulsoup
python
nonetype
python
ubuntu
etc.

While extracting data from the stack overflow site, we are facing problems in scraping the tags for the questions. We are able to scrape the tags but they are not being displayed question wise. The problem is that for each question the class is different
For example: if the question has python as the only the tag, then the class is "tags t-python"
and if there are more tags then it continues like, "tags t-python t-python 3.x and so on"
Depending on the number of tags in each question.
Could you please suggest what should we do.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried with a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you scraping SO instead of using the API in the first place?

Comment: Which API should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your approach from searching for an HTML class name to the `href` link. For instance, scraping this question will yield:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
question_html = str(urllib.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332852/how-to-web-scrape-tags-for-stack-overflow-questions-using-beautifulsoup').read())
tags = {i.text for i in soup(question_html, 'lxml').find_all('a', href=True) if re.findall('questions/tagged/[\w\W]+$', i['href'])}
```

Output:

```
set([u'python', u'beautifulsoup'])
```

Scraping a question with a greater amount of tags will yield:

```
question_html = str(urllib.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337964/returning-removed-elements-in-a-doubly-linked-list').read())
tags = {i.text for i in soup(question_html, 'lxml').find_all('a', href=True) if re.findall('questions/tagged/[\w\W]+$', i['href'])}
```

Output:

```
set([u'python', u'doubly-linked-list', u'return-value', u'python-3.x'])
```